# Saving multilayer canvas angularjs javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a multilayer canvas that I want to save locally with a button(it will eventually have to be saved on aws but for now I am trying to figure out how to do it locally). I want one png file of the entire canvas and not just one layer. How would I do this, I've tried a few tutorials but they didn't seem to work. I have just started using javascript and angularjs so bear with me

AngularJS/HTML

```
<div style="position: relative; border: 1px solid black;">
<canvas id="layer1" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 0;"></canvas>

<canvas id="layer2" width="200" height="200" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: 1;"></canvas>
</div> 

<p><button onclick="body()">Body</button></p>
<p><button onclick="hairstyle1()">Hair style 1</button></p>
<p><button onclick="hairstyle2()">Hair style 2</button></p>
```

Javascript

```
function body() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('layer1');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
};
imageObj.src = 'body.png';
}

function hairstyle1() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('layer2');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 7, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
};
imageObj.src = 'hair1.png';
}

function hairstyle2() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('layer2');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 var imageObj = new Image();

 imageObj.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 50, 7, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
};
imageObj.src = 'hair2.png';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the canvas's are the same size, you can use `drawImage` to draw each one on another canvas.

```
var newCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
newCanvas.width = 200;
newCanvas.height = 200;
var newCtx = newCanvas.getContext('2d');
newCtx.drawImage(document.getElementById("layer1"), 0, 0);
newCtx.drawImage(document.getElementById("layer2"), 0, 0);
// convert to url
console.log(newCanvas.toDataURL());
```

Esentially, canvas's can be treated as image objects as well.

Comment: I see what you are saying. The only issue is that I need the user to choose which layers they want from buttons on the html side. For example I have two functions for layer2 either hairstyle1 or hairstyle2. Both go to layer2 and there is a clearRect in there to clear that layer first so they can choose only one hairstyle. Wouldn't this way you proposed draw both hairstyles or is there a way around this? Thank you

Comment: @Andre no, it will draw whatever is on the canvas at the moment.